# A question about infinite cardinal numbers.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume the Continuum Hypothesis as well as the Axiom of Choice. Let S be the smallest uncountable ordinal number. Let C(S) be the set of all mappings of S into the continuum such that the set of all elements of S which are not mapped onto zero is at most countable. Is the cardinal number of C(S) equal to (the cardinal number of) S?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you’re assuming the continuum hypothesis, you are in effect asking about the cardinality of the set of functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ that map all but countably many reals to $0$. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the set of such functions. If $f\in\mathscr{F}$, let $A_f=\{x\in\Bbb R:f(x)\ne 0\}$; $A_f$ is a countable subset of $\Bbb R$. $\Bbb R$ has

$$(2^{\omega})^\omega=2^{\omega\cdot\omega}=2^\omega$$

countable subsets. If $A$ is one of them, there are

$$(2^\omega)^{|A|}=2^{\omega\cdot|A|}=\begin{cases}
2^\omega,&\text{if }A\ne\varnothing\\
1,&\text{if }A=\varnothing
\end{cases}$$

functions from $A$ to $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. Thus, for each non-empty countable $A\subseteq\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ there are $2^\omega$ functions $f\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $A_f=A$, and there are $2^\omega$ such sets $A$, so $|\mathscr{F}|=2^\omega$, which under the continuum hypothesis is equal to $\omega_1$, your $S$.

In fact $|\mathscr{F}|=2^\omega$ irrespective of whether $\mathsf{CH}$ holds, since $\omega_1$ has $2^\omega$ countable subsets. This follows from the calculation

$$2^\omega\le\omega_1^\omega\le(2^\omega)^\omega=2^\omega\;,$$

since of course $\omega_1\le2^\omega$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$  Then there are $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}$ countable sets of elements of $S$ that you can send to non-zero values becuse each one is a function from $\Bbb N$ to $\aleph_1$ and for each of those there are $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}$ ways to pick the values to send them to.

Comment: Many thanks for your responses. I did not see the neat argument which implies that it is not necessary to assume CH. It would seem then that my S could be any uncountable ordinal number-not just the smallest one.

Comment: This works for any cardinal with cofinality greater than $\aleph_0$

Comment: That is very interesting. So if S is any cardinal number with countable cofinality, the cardinal number of C(S) is greater than S.